# Expresion regular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, regex

Quisiera consultar como puedo obtener una expresion regular para obtener el resultado entre corchetes sin considerar los sub corchetes me explico con un ejemplo

```
let txt = F[aaa(0,0,0)] otra texto F[bbb(1,1,1)]
let regExp = /F\[([^\]]+)\]/g;
let matches = txt.match(regExp);
```

Para lo cual obtner un arreglo con lo siguiente :

```
F[aaa(0,0,0)], 
F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

El problema lo tengo cuando tengo lo siguiente :

```
let txt = F[aaa( F[ccc(2,2,2)],0,0)] otra texto F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

Para lo cual obtener un arreglo con lo siguiente:

```
F[aaa( F[ccc(2,2,2)]  , F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

y lo que me gustaría obtener seria lo siguiente :

```
F[aaa( F[ccc(2,2,2)],0,0)] y F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

Además de este caso me gustaria considerar todos los casos posibles por ejemplo para 3 sub corchetes :

```
let txt = F[aaa( F[ccc( F[ddd(3,3,3)],2,2)],0,0)] otra texto F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

Para lo que me gustaria obtener

```
F[aaa( F[ccc( F[ddd(3,3,3)],2,2)],0,0)] y F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final resolvi mi problema al revez fui resolviendo desde la adentro hacia afuera para este

```
let txt = F[aaa( F[ccc( F[ddd(3,3,3)],2,2)],0,0)] otra texto F[bbb(1,1,1)]
```

obtuve

F[ddd(3,3,3)] y F[bbb(1,1,1)]

Y con una función recursiva fui resolviendo hacia afuera

Utilice la siguiente expresión por si a alguien le sirve

```
/F\[([^F\[\]]+)\]/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede conseguir con expresiones recursivas, lamentablemente no están soportadas en javascript.

Para hacerlo en javascript tendrías que especificarlo manualmente en la expresión, pero siempre estará limitado al numero de corchetes interiores que consideres al crear la expresión, hasta 2 corchetes interiores podría ser:

```
let regExp = /F\[(?:[^\[\]]+|\[(?:[^\[\]]+|\[[^\[\]]*\])*\])*\]/g;
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uDI3Ez/5)

O puedes usar la libreria [XRegExp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp), aunque tendrías que añadir de nuevo los delimitadores si los necesitas ya que los elimina.

```
let matches = XRegExp.matchRecursive(txt, 'F\\[', '\\]', 'g');
let newmatches = matches.map(match => 'F[' + match + ']');
```

Por si te interesa en pcre con expresión recursiva podría ser:

```
/(F*)\[(?>[^\[\]]+|(?R))*\]/g
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/E7mVe9/5)